# Inserting data to main and pivot table at the same time

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table, eloquent-relationship

I have three tables `users` table, `user_instrument` table, and `instruments` table 
The columns are as follows :
`users table`
-id
-name
-email
-password

`user_instrument table`
-id
-user_id
-instrument_id

`instruments table`
-id
-instrument_name

Now, in my registration form, along with the basic fields such as name, email, password. I also have an options of instruments that a user can choose.
Whenever a user registers, I want to simultaneously insert the `users table` with the `name, email, password` fields while the `user_instrument table` with `user_id, instrument_id`

I have read the eloquent relationship but all my attempts are just too confusing and doesn't make sense at all. 
Please bare with me :(

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships  Does this help you

Comment: Good to have these documentations.... but also nice if someone can provide answer aside from docs. but thanks tho.